# NextJS multiple dynamic routes with different destionation

Tags: dynamic, routes, next.js, content-management-system

In my project I have the following requirement: having 2 routes that are dynamic but that are going to be drawn by different components.

### More context:

I have a CMS that provides all the info and in most of the cases I'm going to read from a "page" model. This is going to be drawn by the Page component and its going to have a `getServerSideProps` that makes a call to a CMS endpoint to get that information

The endpoint and component are not the same for the other case with a dynamic route

Both types of routes are completely dynamic so I cannot prepare then in advance (or at least I'm trying to find another solution) since they come from the CMS

As an example, I can have this slugs

```
mypage.com/about-us (page endpoint & component)
mypage.com/resource (resources endpoint & component)
```

Both routes are configured using dynamic routes like this

```
{
  source: '/:pages*',
  destination: '/cms/pages'
}
```

The problem here is that it can only match one of the endpoints and the logic for both calling the endpoint and the component used to draw it are completely different

Is there a way of fallbacking to the next matched URL in case that there's more than one that matches similar to the `return {notFound: true}`?

Some solutions that I have are:

- Somehow hardcode all the resources urls (since are less than pages) and pass them as defined routes instead of dynamic routes
- Make some dirty code that will check if the slug is from a resource and if not fallback to a page and then return a Resource component or a Page component depending on that (this idea I like it less since it makes the logic of the Page component super dirty)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you considered changing one of the slugs so that there's no conflict between both dynamic routes? For example, moving the resource endpoints to `mypage.com/resource/resource-1`, so they'd be nested in a `resource` folder under `pages`.

Comment: @juliomalves Its a requirement from product so I cannot do much about this, they have to "collide" but I have to be able to detect that and change the component that draws it

Comment: That's fair enough. Can you tell from the route's path if it's for a page or resource, or do you have to make a call to the CMS to get that information?

Comment: @juliomalves I have to resolve it first using the CMS in order to know it. The only other way is that during build time I can pre-consult and have a json file or something with the resources (since those are less frequently created) but I'm looking for better solutions if they exists (cause I'll have to re-deploy each time I have a new resource)

Comment: I guess you don't have much choice but to go with the second solution you mentioned in your question: have a dynamic route where you'd make the request on the server-side, get the information you need to determine what it is, and then display the appropriate template in your page component.